# Neo4j browser - How to export the graph with having a white background?

Tags: neo4j

When I export the graph as `PNG` through the `Neo4j Browser`, its background color is set to **black** which makes it almost unreadable. How can I customize the exported `PNG` as I want to set its background to **white**?

Detail regarding `Neo4j`:

Version: `3.5.2`

Edition: `Community`

Answer (score 0):

To change to the white background in the Neo4j browser run

:config theme: normal

For more settings and options see:
https://neo4j.com/docs/browser-manual/current/operations/browser-settings/